# Suppress Error message while using cat command

Tags: linux, error-handling, cat

I have a script where I recursively copy the contents of the files in a folder using cat command as follows

```
test -f /tmp/$F || cat $F > /tmp/$F
```

I get the following error

```
cat: read error: Invalid argument
```

I want to know how can I suppress this error. I only have access to shell interpreter (no bash).

Thanks

Comment: Use more quotes ! http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting

Comment: My bad for not quoting well. $F could be a directory so I check for a file by test -f. Anyways this seems to work cat $F 2>/dev/null 1>/tmp/$F

Answer (score 7):

Send error messages to `/dev/null`.

```
cat $F 1>/tmp/$F 2>/dev/null
```