# How do I redirect errors to /dev/null in bash?

Tags: bash

We run daily Selenium tests to test our website and extensions. I wrote a script (according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832193/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-files-containing-a-specific-string-but-not-contain)) to count the number of passed and failed tests. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

today=`TZ='Asia/Tel_Aviv' date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
yesterday=`TZ='Asia/Tel_Aviv' date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "yesterday"`

...

print_test_results()
{
    declare -i passed_tests=0
    declare -i failed_tests=0
    declare -i total_tests=0
    log_suffix="_${file_name}.log"
    yesterday_logs="${log_prefix}${yesterday}_[1,2]*${log_suffix}"
    today_logs="${log_prefix}${today}_0*${log_suffix}"
    for temp_file_name in $yesterday_logs $today_logs ; do
        total_tests+=1
        if grep -q FAILED "$temp_file_name" ; then
            failed_tests+=1
        elif grep -q OK "$temp_file_name" ; then
            passed_tests+=1
        else
            failed_tests+=1
        fi
    done
    echo "<tr>"
    echo "<td>$test_name - $today</td>"
    if [ $passed_tests = "0" ]; then
        echo "<td>$passed_tests passed</td>"
        echo "<td><span style=\"color: red;\">$failed_tests failed</span></td>"
    else
        echo "<td><span style=\"color: green;\">$passed_tests passed</span></td>"
        echo "<td>$failed_tests failed</td>"
    fi
    echo "<td>$total_tests tests total</td>"
    echo "</tr>"
}

file_name="chrome_gmail_1_with_extension_test"
test_name="Chrome Gmail 1 With Extension Test"
print_test_results

...
```

But the problem is, if the files are not there (`in $yesterday_logs $today_logs`), I get error messages. How do I redirect these error messages to /dev/null? I want to redirect them to /dev/null from the script, and not from the line calling the script - I want this script to never show error messages about files which don't exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppress Error message while using cat command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178935/suppress-error-message-while-using-cat-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I changed this line to:

```
for temp_file_name in `ls $yesterday_logs $today_logs 2>/dev/null` ; do
    total_tests+=1
    if grep -q FAILED "$temp_file_name" ; then
        failed_tests+=1
    elif grep -q OK "$temp_file_name" ; then
        passed_tests+=1
    else
        failed_tests+=1
    fi
done
```

Then only the `ls` errors are directed to `/dev/null`.

Comment: This solution has several problems.  ① Spaces in `$yesterday_logs` etc. will  run you into trouble.  Use doublequotes to avoid that, even if the current implementation surely has no spaces.  Things change over time.  ② Using `ls` to list all directory entries has a similar problem, e. g. if any entry contains spaces or newlines or such.  ③ Using backticks for command output capturing is deprecated.  You should use `$(...)` instead nowadays.

Answer (score 10):

Just for the record:

In general, to suppress error messages in bash, use `command 2>/dev/null`.  So in your case you should use `grep -q OK 2>/dev/null`.

But as your case also shows (from what I read in the comments) this is a risky thing to do, as it cloaks errors you might have in your code.  "I want this script to never print error messages" should only be said when one knows *all* possible error cases which could possibly occur.

Comment: Hi @Alfe, `grep -q OK` is not enough because I grep each file twice. How can I add `2>/dev/null` to the command `for temp_file_name in $yesterday_logs $today_logs ; do ...`?

Comment: Of course, the redirection only works for the command it is applied to, so you will have to repeat the phrase on each command (`grep`) you start.  To apply it to a scope, append it like this:  `for i in …; do …; done 2>/dev/null`, i. e. right at the end of it, after the closing `done`; then all commands inside that scope will be affected.

Comment: Thanks, I'm accepting this answer since that's what I meant, I just didn't know where to put the `2>/dev/null`.

Comment: @Uri: As @Alfe himself added in his answer that **this is a risky thing to do**. If you use `shopt -s nullglob` as I suggested then `grep` won't even run on non-existing filenames.

Comment: @anubhava I want to suppress error messages in the specific for loop, not in the entire script. Can you explain to me what `shopt -s nullglob` does and how it affects the script? If I can suppress error messages only in the for loop, but not inside the loop, it's better. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You can just add `2>/dev/null` after `done` to suppress all errors in `for` loop but again suppressing is not a good idea and may fail your script quietly. It is always better to fix only one certain pattern you know is going to cause error.

Comment: Normally, a glob pattern (like `foo*`) will be expanded to all matching file names, separated by spaces (like `fooone footwo foothree`) and if there are *no* matching file names, it will be expanded to itself (i. e. to `foo*`). In this normal case, a program like `grep` will receive a glob pattern which does not match a file name, hence it will typically fail (`file not found`). With the shell option `shopt -s nullglob`, a glob pattern which does not match any existing file names will be removed entirely (the argument is stripped from the command), thus a `grep` will not get a wrong file name.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your script you can place this line at start:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

This will not match anything if your glob pattern doesn't find any matching file. Otherwise whole glob pattern is returned when you use something like:

```
for temp_file_name in $yesterday_logs $today_logs; do ... done
```

Comment: Yes, it works. I'm accepting this answer. I had a typo in the date -d command, that's why I received the error message.