# How to use 'grep -v' on 'du' output in Linux?

Tags: grep, du

I'm running below command:

```
du -hs * | sort -hr | grep -v "*directory*"
```

But, I getting output as below:

```
[myuser@ip-1-2-3-4 opt]$ du -hs * | sort -hr | grep -v "*cannot read directory*"
du: cannot read directory ‘XYZ’: Permission denied
du: cannot read directory ‘ABC/DEF’: Permission denied
80G dir1
27G dir2
15G dir3
```

I want to exclude lines: `cannot read directory`.

Anything am I missing here ?

Comment: Replace `du -hs *` with `du -hs * 2>/dev/null`?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want those error lines? If, by any chance, the disk space loss is inside one of those directories, you won't know about it anymore.

Comment: `*` at the beginning of a regex is interpreted as a literal asterisk. You are probably looking for `.*` which is the regular expression for "any character, repeated zero or more times, as many as possible" but you don't need a wildcard here; `grep` looks for a match anywhere in the line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between glob-style patterns and regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702202/what-are-the-differences-between-glob-style-patterns-and-regular-expressions)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901741/how-do-i-redirect-errors-to-dev-null-in-bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "cannot read" lines are on STDERR, so a normal pipe would not process them further.

To filter it:

```
du -hs * 2>&1 | sort -hr | grep -v 'cannot read directory'
```

P.S.:
(Also it is enough to match on the "cannot read directory string")